# Jquery Ajax loading data into Bootstrap Table

Tags: jquery, datatable, bootstrap-4, columnsorting

I am loading bootstrap table from server with JSON data. By default data table has sorting functionality. Inside table td colour  changing based on value. For that I have written this code:

```
"fnRowCallback": function ( nRow, mData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull  ) {
                if(mData['state'] == 'Healthy'){

                     $('td', nRow).eq(1).addClass('green');
                }

                if(mData['state'] == 'Non Healthy'){

                     $('td', nRow).eq(1).addClass('red');
                }

                if(mData['state'] == 'Degraded'){

                     $('td', nRow).eq(1).addClass('yellow');
                }

                if(mData['state'] == 'Shutting Down'){

                     $('td', nRow).eq(1).addClass('red');
                }
            }
```

This is working fine. but at the same time when I am doing sorting on that column I am loosing the colour of that td.

Comment: can you add jsfidde example to help us understand problem better

Comment: Else you can create executable code in StackOverflow by following the steps in the blog post https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/